# Unknown three part signature

Tags: cryptography

I have received a string which is supposed to be a cryptographic signature. I have access to a certificate which should let me verify the signature. However, I am rather confused about the structure of the signature.

I was expecting a byte string, likely base64-encoded. Instead, I received three lines, each 255 characters long, comprised of hex characters, and padded with trailing or leading zeroes.

Unfortunately, I have very little and somewhat uncertain information:

- Payload: "Hello Crypto World"
- Hashing Algorithm: SHA256
- Crypto Algorithm: RSA (not certain)
- PKCS7 is likely involved

The following is roughly the structure of the signature. Note that the string contains mostly random hex characters. I preserved only the length of the (non) padded sections. And I discovered that the first line contains the payload, so I preserved that part also. Since I am uncertain about this string, I don't want to risk potentially publishing a private key, that's why the rest is just random hex characters.

```
1342120FF49C008D19FCA5208C216A8C69E11DE084442AA66B786A0F010766BE82238BEE9BAB9B9DA085E89A41BE8B660A109582F2782987780C6CEB5F85AE1D0A48656C6C6F2043727970746F20576F726C6400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005518C31F61B521823A97E4995D0F4E85B432A73FC0FD098B489D2C9AC533E19BA253AF93D275D906A043975FA03B86A15D993B944DCBF135156A378163E38
042669BAF26B40FA9EDD9460D089DB1725778EB9304CA3034291C21CFB5B750000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

In python this is how I discovered the payload in the first line.

```
>>> bytes.fromhex(line_one + "0")
>>> b'...Hello Crypto World\x00\x00...'
```

Note that it was necessary to append the line with another character ("0") as the line is only 255 characters long which wouldn't translate to full bytes.

I have played around with a python crypto library (`pycryptodome`) trying to make sense of this, to no avail. I have googled, particularly regarding PKCS7, but couldn't quite make sense of this either.

Using the same crypto library I was able to `unpad` each line, which simply stripped away some of the trailing zeroes leaving me with only 207 instead of 255 characters.

**My Questions**
What kind of format is this?
How can I turn this into or extract only the signature part (byte string, base64 string)?

Any help to steer me in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:3072 > key.pem`, `echo "Hello Crypto World" >m`, `openssl sha256 -binary <m >mh`, `openssl pkeyutl -sign -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -in mh -inkey key.pem -out sig`,
`openssl pkeyutl -verify -pkeyopt digest:sha256 -in mh -sigfile sig -inkey key.pem`. The sig should be 384 bytes or 768 hex chars. But the number of 0 in your is suspicious.

Comment: Can you shed some light on the background for this - is this some crypto crackme/riddle/school work? With your data being fuzzed it's impossible to experiment in order to help you out and I have my doubts that this is some kind of known standard format. `PKCS#7` could be a clue as to the structure of your data, or it may just point to `PKCS#7 padding` once the data is decrypted. Why is everything so uncertain?

Comment: This is actually for a production system. The software we're using offers capabilities to sign payloads and verify signatures. However, documentation is very scarce or non-existent. It seems the signing/verification is only supported for within that system or between two of the same type of systems. We're trying to communicate with the outside world (HTTPS) and verify the sender's/system's identity. We can get a signature of a known payload (as seen above), but can't make much sense of it. We have since moved on to a workaround, using a separate program to take care of the signing.

Comment: I'd probably just reverse engineer the code in the software to find out what's up with the 3 lines, unless that proves difficult (virtualized code or similar) given all the uncertainties. Is the software publicly accessible (legally)?